# Unable to shut down laptop after Logging Out of Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, password, username

I logged into the Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and instead of installing it... I pressed the Log Out button, thinking of installing it some other time.

But then a screen appeared asking for Username and Password.

I typed in my name as the User name and a password of my choice..I was halfway through typing my password..just then I remembered that I had to Login as 'root' so I hurriedly pressed the Back button... but instead the user name and half password I typed.. got submitted.

Now it is asking for User name and Password and when I type the ones which I had initially typed..its showing Login Error :(

But the problem doesn't end here... m unable to shut down my laptop.. its been more than 12 hours and m stuck at this login screen... plzzz help me out!

Comment: “Instead of installing”? Are you trying Ubuntu in live mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re trying Ubuntu in live mode, the username is “ubuntu” without any passwords, i.e. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> when prompting for password.

Meanwhile, in such situations simply press and hold the power button to turn the computer off.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running from a live CD/DVD/USB and have not yet installed Ubuntu, and you clicked Log Off, that's not part of the installation. It's not asking you what username and password you want to use in the system you're installing. It's asking for the username and password *for the live environment.*

As [AliNa says](https://askubuntu.com/a/344485/22949), the username is `ubuntu` and the password is blank (assuming you have not changed it in the live CD/DVD/USB since you booted from it, which you probably have not).

If for some reason you want to shut down on the login screen (for example, if that username and password doesn't work), holding down the power button is not the best way to do it. A very clean way to restart is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

But you should be able to log back in to the live CD/DVD/USB system with the username `ubuntu` and the blank password.

If you're running from a live CD/DVD/USB and you want to install Ubuntu, and the installation is not started, you probably selected *Try Ubuntu without installing* rather than *Install Ubuntu*. If that's the case, then when you're ready to install, you can click the *Install Ubuntu* icon on the Unity launcher, which is the bar of icons on the left side of the desktop.